# react-native app, does not show some components on Iphone 5s

Tags: ios, layout, react-native

I'm new to react-native. I'm trying to test my app on different Iphone models. In 5S some components can not be seen, I believe it is something about layouts just like in Swift. Due I am new to React, I'm living difficulty with handling this problem. Do you have any advice how to solve this problem that my App looks same on all apple devices?

Comment: Any way you can show some code for the view? If you have any overflowing height in your view, wrapping it in a scrollview may help, or you may need to detect device height and resize components based on the dimension.

Comment: yeap,there are lots of pages. It almost works without any problem. Just several problems related with components' place  and 1 button is not shown.

Comment: You can try with add backgroundColor to component, to see if its render anyway. Is this some specific component (from outer lib) or react native components?